# Curved image hyperlink

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a round image, say, (where the image uses an alpha channel) such that a hyperlink wrapped around it will only register the actual image and not the alpha'ed out bit?

If not, is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at CSS image maps, I can give an example tomorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a Image map for an Image.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map

Comment: Image maps support rects, circle or polygon as shap. Depending on the complexity of your shap you can approximate it, with few points.

Comment: Guess so... approximate it is!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using CSS to solve this problem.

```
.yourclass {
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Change the values to what you think is right, the -moz- is for a firefox fix.

Comment: But what is the point of adding a border? That has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Doorknob Not sure, but that might just work -- it's not about adding a border but making the element itself behave as if it were round.

Comment: @KevinBoucher `Not sure, but that might just work` ...okay then? It won't.

Comment: Oh for image mapping a simple way would be to go to [Image Map](http://www.image-maps.com/)

Comment: @Doorknob Nice attitude. Did you try it? You didn't seem to even understand what he was getting at with his suggestion.

Comment: @KevinBoucher What would be the point of adding a border? It has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Doorknob Well, it doesn't work, but if you look at this example you will see that the red div does not show the pointer cursor in the corners (b/c of the border-radius), but for the (black) anchor tag that magic doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/JYcmw/

Comment: @Doorknob It does work! It occurred to me to apply the same treatment to the image itself and voila! Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/JYcmw/ You should consider remove that down-vote.

Comment: @user1858233 +1 for creative thinking and a solution that does work: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/JYcmw/

Comment: @KevinBoucher that fiddle doesn't work for me. Chrome on Windows 7, if that matters.

Comment: @Doorknob Nope, not on Chrome/Vista either. Works in Fx and IE9, though. Point is, it was a thoughtful and effective suggestion (if not solution). (You should still remove your down-vote.)

Comment: @KevinBoucher I did, someone else downvoted. How does this even work though?

Comment: @KevinBoucher thanks for trying it out man. I posted this answer when I was twelve years old and it makes me laugh reading what my naive self wrote.

Comment: @James LOL. I always enjoy these legacy posts too! Hope all is well with you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want that ugly square outline removed around it when you click on it?
Try adding to the css:

```
img {border: none}
```

and on the actual round image A tag, turn off the outline:

```
<a href="#" style="outline: none"><img src="roundimage.jpg" /></a>
```

You'll still get the pointer cursor off of the round part - if you want the pointer to only show up when you hover over the round part - make an image map out of the image and set the map area shape to round.